# What is the best way to update the Admob plugin in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-mobile-ads

[error code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKovs.png)I have an old project on an old version of Unity (2018.4.36f LTS) with an even older Google Admob plugin in it. I would like to update the Google Admob SDK to have all the latest features, like the App Open Ad. But I don't know how to do it (PC running Windows 11) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest sdk from [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases)

It makes no difference what version of Windows you have. After downloading the sdk, open the Unity editor in the project you want and then drag or double click the downloaded file into Unity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The thing is, if I do that, I might have some duplicate files ? The last time I tried to import the admob sdk into a project that already had the admob sdk, I got a lot of errors in the console

Comment: If the sdk version is too old, you should delete the plugins and the entire GoogleMobileAds folder Then you will find some errors, all you have to do is add the modern sdk and the errors will be gone Anyway, if there is an error, write it here and I will help you to solve it, God willing

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I'm going to try that right away. Hopefully everything's going to work soon

Comment: So, i just did what you told me to do, and i have 1 error in the console:
'Assets\Script\AdManag.cs(35,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RewardBasedVideoAd' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: Double click on the error and the code editor will open Take a picture of line 35 and send it here

Comment: I've added the picture

Comment: Replace it with Rewarded if the error persists, attach the file and the added sdk number